# Start a thread when Activity Starts

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following code below

```
public class StartGameActivity extends BaseActivity {
   public TextView txtCustomerCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_game);
        this.txtCustomerCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerCount);
        testThread();
    }

    public void testThread(){       
         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  int count = 0;
                  boolean stop = false;
                  while(!stop){
                      txtCustomerCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                      fakework(2000);
                      count++;
                      if(count > 99){
                          stop = true;
                      }
                  }
              }
         };
         new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    public void fakework(int lasts){
        try {
           Thread.sleep(lasts);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

now what I want here is to start the thread as the `onCreate()` is executed but the code above returns an error like this

> 07-10 17:20:20.046: E/AndroidRuntime(6247):
>   android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {yens.alisa.menu/yens.alisa.menu.StartGameActivity} did not call
>   through to super.onStart()

where I went wrong? If you can please explain further because I am just beginning to learn android. thank you.

Comment: Did you added onStart() ?

Comment: Stacktrace obviously not related to the problem :( I downvoted for not reading the explicit error message.

Comment: @C4stor that is only the error log that is shown, you may want a screenshot for an evidence?

Comment: I don't think you posted the whole trace. Also, looking at your code: `txtCustomerCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));` should be called on the UI thread and you should also exit the loop if the activity finished itself.

Comment: @Mahan : I believe that the error is here. What I don't believe is that it is in anyway related to the part of the code you shown or anykind of multithreading problem. blackbelt is most probably right

Answer (score 1):

Given the stacktrace the only thing that could cause it is that `BaseActivity` has not called `super.onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

Updating a user interface element from within a thread other than the main thread violates a key rule of Android development. 
In order to update the user interface, therefore, it will be necessary to implement a Handler for the thread or use AsyncTask.

Though this might not be the problem. check BaseActivity like @blackbelt suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a view element directly from a background thread.
Also, If you are using `AsynTask` in your program, only `OnpreExecute` and `OnPostExecute` method have access directly to view element as they run on UI thread. The `doInBackground` method run on separate thread.

In Your case and in `doInBackground` of `Asyntask`  you can use--

```
txtCustomerCount.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txtCustomerCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));                          
                        }
                    });
```

However Your error log is not related to the problem.